# Modify configuration python script inside modification tool script (python)

Tags: python, scripting

I have problem:
I have a configuration python file.
I have another main script with few options to add and modify dicts & lists & sets inside the configuration file.
Problem: All is great, The changes are made BUT when I close the main script, nothing is saved on the configuration file.
Question: What should I do to fix it?

Thanks all.

Comment: This is a very broad question: without seeing your script, it is not possible to help. Can you post a stripped down version?

Answer (score 0):

**config_raw file:(sample)**

## Database information setup (Containes list of dicts).

> databases_list = {}

**main running script sample:**

```
elif ch is 3:
    for key, value in db_con_menu.iteritems():
        print key, value
    ans = input('Enter your diseired choice >')

    while not (ans in db_con_menu):
        ans = input('Wrong selection! please select again..>')

    if ans is 1:
       add_new_database()
    elif ans is 2:
        edit_existing_database()
    elif ans is 3:
        remove_existing_database()
    else:
        main_flow()
```

Each function is suppose to edit the config file and do manipulation on databses_list dict.
it's work and the change made but I want to update the file so when i close the script (the main script of the tool) all the changes i have made will save!

Thanks.